# When i called specific (parameter) from extended Class Object eg: subject value shows undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
class Students{
            constructor(name,age,subject){
                this.myname = name;
                this.myage = age;
                this.mysubject = subject;
            }
            extraclass(){
                return `This ${this.myname} and my age ${this.myage} and my favorite
                subject is ${this.mysubject}`;
            }
        }

        class Dance extends Students{
            constructor(name,age,subject,dance){
                super(name,age,subject);
                this.mydance = dance;
            }
            fun3(){
                return `This is extraclass ${super.extraclass()} and this is my dance ${this.mydance}`;
            }
        }

        var student1 = new Dance('Aniket',30,'Maths','Scuba');
        // document.write(student1.fun3()); This works when i call the method
        
        document.write(student1.subject);  
        // When i call specific parameter eg: subject value shows undefined`
```

```js
class Students{
            constructor(name,age,subject){
                this.myname = name;
                this.myage = age;
                this.mysubject = subject;
            }
            extraclass(){
                return `This ${this.myname} and my age ${this.myage} and my favorite
                subject is ${this.mysubject}`;
            }
        }

        class Dance extends Students{
            constructor(name,age,subject,dance){
                super(name,age,subject);
                this.mydance = dance;
            }
            fun3(){
                return `This is extraclass ${super.extraclass()} and this is my dance ${this.mydance}`;
            }
        }

        var student1 = new Dance('Aniket',30,'Maths','Scuba');
        // document.write(student1.fun3()); This works when i call the method
        
        document.write(student1.subject);
```

One parent class created with 3 parameters (name,age,subject) and than extended the class to child class Dance But When i call parent class each (parameter) inside new object, the value is showing undefined.

var student1 = new Dance('Aniket',30,'Maths','Scuba');
document.write(student1.subject);

Comment: student1.mysubject - you are confusing constructor parameter names with object properties.

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the second snippet?

Answer (score 1):

use the property / attribute name, not the constructor parameter name:

```js
document.write(student1.mysubject);
```

also, you can try to view the object : console.table( student1 );

Comment: Agree, except the simple param names are better. Change `mysubject` to `subject`. This is a matter of taste, but there's such a thing as objectively better taste.

Comment: @danh I agree that converging the names of variables and parameters are a good idea, it is easier to keep track of.